# How to add a static route to a router that I do not control?

Tags: linux, routing, vpn, arp

I am working on a program to control a VPN router running on a Linux SBC. In order to have traffic for the VPN network come back, I need to add a static route to the network's gateway... I don't want to have to reconfigure the gateway in order to do that. e.g. perhaps I don't have the password, etc.

Is there a reliable protocol I can use to push the route out to the gateway? I know ARP poising is not a good solution. Is there a good solution to solve this problem? And hopefully, one that will work with typical residential network equipment, cable modems, etc.

This is not really a VPN question so much as it is a routing protocol question.

A scenario...

Home network: 192.168.1.0/24

Home gateway: 192.168.1.1

VPN gateway: 192.168.1.2

VPN network: 192.168.99.0/24

VPN client: 192.168.99.3

VPN gateway has forwarding and masquerading enabled. Home gateway needs a static route from 192.168.99.0/24 to 192.168.1.2. I need to find a way to inject that route without having admin access to the Home gateway.

Comment: Routing protocols exist for exactly this reason, but they will need to be enabled on the gateway router. RIP is really simple, and probably good enough if this is a home setup without a strong need for security. OSPF is much more complicated but does provide security. Being able to inject routes would allow you to impersonate any http (not https) site so (except for bugs) is not going to be possible. You mention ARP poisoning, this works at a different layer.

Comment: You might be able to use proxy arp but you'd be much better adding the route to the router. Unfortunately you say you can't do that